# A message '-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied' appears after linux login

Tags: linux, redhat

I log in to redhat server 7.4 by putty.

```
login as: john
cescalante@192.168.1.10's password:
Last login: Mon Sep 12 10:45:16 2022 from 172.24.7.200
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied    
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

How can I know the reason of 'Permission denied' message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/dev/null file became regular file](https://serverfault.com/questions/551628/dev-null-file-became-regular-file)

Comment: Yes, somehow it helped. My idea was to solve it without rebooting. However, it had to be done.